# Xamarin добавление References

Tags: xamarin

Всем привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли в Xamarin Forms Portable проект добавлять References ?
У меня почему-то список пустой, не могу даже подключить System.Data
Но в Андроид проекте все ссылки есть и подключить их можно
Или же в Portable нужно только вручную dll'ки добавлять из фолдера?
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Portable` проекте нельзя добавлять в References `System.Data`

Если вам нужно работать с базой можно использовать MysqlLite как указано в документации.

К недостаткам PCL относится :

- Так как портативная библиотека классов разделяется между несколькими
  приложениями, библиотеки специфичные для платформы нельзя добавлять
  в references (например. Community.CsharpSqlite.WP7).
- PCL не должен включать в себя классы, которые могуть бы доступны в MonoTouch и Mono для Android сразу (например, DllImport или System.IO.File).